# Websphere Virtual Host

Tags: port, web-applications, websphere

IBM WAS 8 gives option to create virtual hosts.
At the time of WAR deployment, I am able to map the application to a particular virtual host.
For each virtual host, I am able to assign a port number (There is no protocol defined for the virtual host port - so, will it apply for HTTP?).

However, the application is not accessible using that port number.
Neither is the application accessible on the normal HTTP port of the server.

What is the gap here? Server doesn't listen on ports defined for virtual hosts other than default_host? Is a separate Http server required to listen on that port and forward the request to WAS?

Comment: Could you please show us what is the message you get when access the application? Is this a "Virtual Host not found" message?

Comment: I have two WAR files. First WAR application is mapped to default host. I access it using WAS HTTP port and it works fine. Second WAR application is mapped to test_host. test_host host alias port setting i changed to 7071. I am trying to access application as <WASserverIP>:7071/WebApp2 . I am getting connection refused error on Google Chrome for second application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A virtual host definition by itself doesn't create any HTTP ports. It is only used to specify which applications accept HTTP requests received via which HTTP ports (this includes HTTP ports local to the application server and HTTP ports on a Web server in front of the application server). To actually listen on a given port, you have the following options:

1. Change the port number of the default HTTP port (but I guess that's not what you want; you probably want to listen on an *additional* port).
2. Configure a Web server that listens on the desired port and that forwards to WAS.
3. [Create an additional HTTP port on the application server](http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/21/was-create-additional-http-port.html).